# ReadFileEx, variable length - a few questions

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, 64-bit, overlapped-io

I'm trying to read from `stderr` of a child process. The data is lines of text created with `sprintf(stderr, "some debug info\n")`. I'm using `ReadFileE`x with a completion routine. I don't know how many lines of text or how long each line will be. So, what do I put as the `nNumberOfBytesToRead` parameter?

My guess is I put the max size of my buffer, which I will make 4k; although I don't know if that's an optimal size. I'm guessing that if the line written to `stderr` is shorter than 4k, the completion routine won't fire. I'm guessing that when the 4k is reached but more data remains, I have to fire off another `ReadFileEx` within the completion routine. I'll know this is the case because `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. I'm hoping that I get a call when the buffer isn't full, but the child process has exited. I'm not sure I get a completion callback when the child process exits, because I passed the `stderr` write handle to the child when I created it; maybe I get the callback when *I* close that handle. Are there any race conditions when the child closes `wrt` to my reading `stderr`?

Here is the psuedo code of how the process and handles are created:

```
Attr.bInheritHandle = true
CreatePipe(&hr, &hw, &Attr, 0) and SetHandleInformation(hX, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT) on hX the child uses.
Si.hStdXXX = handles from CreatePipe that child uses
CreateProcess(inherit=true, &Si)
```

Details (Tx extension is a wrapper that throws errors):

```
HANDLE Create() {
    STARTUPINFO SI, *pSI = NULL;
    bool fInherit = m_fInherit;
    if (m_fStdOut || m_fStdIn || m_fStdErr) {
        fInherit = true;
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Attr;
        Attr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
        Attr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
        Attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
        if (m_fStdOut) // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. The child will use the write.
            CHandle::CreatePipe(m_hStdOutR, m_hStdOutW, &Attr, CP_INHERIT_WRITE);
        if (m_fStdErr) // Create a pipe for the child process's STDERR. The child will use the write.
            CHandle::CreatePipe(m_hStdErrR, m_hStdErrW, &Attr, CP_INHERIT_WRITE);
        if (m_fStdIn) // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. The child will use the read.
            CHandle::CreatePipe(m_hStdInR, m_hStdInW, &Attr, CP_INHERIT_READ);
        // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
        // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
        ZeroStruct(SI);
        SI.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
        SI.hStdError = m_hStdErrW, SI.hStdOutput = m_hStdOutW, SI.hStdInput = m_hStdInR;
        SI.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        pSI = &SI;
    }
    //  m_fCpu, m_fNuma are masks to set affinity to cpus or numas
    CreateProcessTx(NULL, m_szCmdLine, fInherit, m_fFlags, pSI, &m_pi, m_fCpu, m_fNuma, 5);
    m_hProc = m_pi.hProcess;
    m_hThread = m_pi.hThread;
    if (!m_fThread)
        m_hThread.Close();
    return m_hProc;
}

static void CreatePipe(CHandle &hRead, CHandle &hWrite, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* pAttr, BYTE fInheritMask) {
    HANDLE hReadTmp = NULL, hWriteTmp = NULL;
    CreatePipeTx(hReadTmp, hWriteTmp, pAttr);
    SetHandleInformation(hReadTmp, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, (fInheritMask&CP_INHERIT_READ) ? HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT : 0); 
    SetHandleInformation(hWriteTmp, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, (fInheritMask&CP_INHERIT_WRITE) ? HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT : 0);
    hRead = hReadTmp;
    hWrite = hWriteTmp;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using handles created with `CreatePipe`?

Comment: @RR good point.  I edited the post to add in some of the parts of the code that create the pipes and process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous pipes created with `CreatePipe` can't used asynchronously.  From the Windows SDK documentation:

> Asynchronous (overlapped) read and write operations are not supported by anonymous pipes.
>   This means that you cannot use the ReadFileEx and WriteFileEx functions with anonymous pipes. >In addition, the lpOverlapped parameter of ReadFile and WriteFile is ignored when these >functions are used with anonymous pipes.

Basically `CreatePipe` doesn't accept a `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag, and asynchronous I/O requires that you use the flag when creating the file handle.

You'll have to use `CreateNamedPipe` to create named pipes. The question [Overlapped I/O on anonymous pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645/overlapped-i-o-on-anonymous-pipe) has answer with a link to a replacement function `MyCreatePipeEx` you can use.

Your completion port should receive a zero length read event after attempting to read from a pipe that has been closed on the other end.

To read a variable amount of data from the client process just issue read requests of whatever size you find convenient and be prepared to handle read events that are shorter than you requested. Don't interpret a short but non-zero length as EOF. Keep issuing read requests until you get a zero length read or an error.

Also `WaitForMultipleObjects` won't work with completion routines, as they're only called while the thread is in an [alterable state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363772(v=vs.85).aspx). Use `WaitForMultipleObjectEx` with the `bAlertable` argument set to to true. This function will return `WAIT_IO_COMPLETION` after running one or more completion routines. In that case you'll probably want to immediately call `WaitForMultipleObjectEx` again.

Comment: I was just coming to that conclusion as my call to ReadFileEx was blocking.  I thought I might be screwed till you said to try CreateNamedPipe, which I am currently doing.  Do you know anything about reading the variable length?

Comment: Hmm... missed that part of your question, I updated my answer to address that.

Comment: @RR do i issue the read request again from withing the completion function?  I think I have to, since my WaitForMultipleObjects is waiting on multiple child processes - not on all of the reading from stderr/stdout.

Comment: Yup, call `ReadWriteEx` again in your completion routine.

Comment: ReadFileEx doesn't block anymore.  However, I am not receiving and callbacks.  sprintf(stderr...) in the child is not blocking.  WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)..) is blocking in the child.  That doesn't block if I do a non overlapped ReadFile.  It seems that my overlapped reading on the handles isn't working, but the handles are valid to write to and can be read with non overlapped ReadFile.

Comment: You have to use `WaitForMultipleObjectEx` with `bAlertable` argument set to to true. Otherwise completion routines won't be called.

Comment: bAlertable!  Something is happening now!  Let me clear the dust a bit around here and see if its working...

Comment: Add that bit about WaitForMultipleObjectsEX to your answer to benefit anyone else who reads it, and ill accept.  Thanks a lot!  I was waiting on the proc handles.  I wonder if that flag = true lets windows wake your thread up to handle the callback and then it puts your thread back to sleep.