# How does cmd.exe display stdout even though the process doesn't flush?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I used [this MSDN code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) to hook stdout and stderr for a child process, (except that I'm calling `PeekNamedPipe` first so that I don't block) and all is well except that for stdout if the process doesn't flush then I don't see the output of the process immediately. Stderr seems to be automatically flushed whenever something is sent to it, but stdout buffers the results.

Suddenly I'm amazed that the cmd.exe shell process can print results immediately when you step through code in Visual Studio. I would like to do so too. How does it do it?

Comment: very simply. not use c/c++ library for output. use winapi - `WriteFile` or `WriteConsoleW`

Comment: @Eelke, C standard I/O defaults to full buffering when writing to stdout if it's a pipe or disk file. However, cmd.exe does not use C standard I/O -- or even C low I/O (e.g. `_write`), but rather uses the Windows API directly. If it's writing to a console, CMD  uses `WriteConsoleW`. Otherwise it writes encoded bytes to stdout via `WriteFile`. If CMD's `/u` option is specified, it writes native UTF-16LE, else it encodes via `WideCharToMultiByte`. For the latter, with `/a` it uses the system ANSI codepage, else it uses the current console input codepage.

Comment: For blocking issue you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294219/createprocess-stdout-with-createnamedpipe-overlapped) similar question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the cmd.exe rather the implementation of the stdio. When printing to stdout it holds the information in a buffer and flushes it periodically (or before shutdown) by a different thread. This behavior is on purpose and used to improve performance. Otherwise, printing will be blocking.

Here is how to make it autoflush after each print command: [C autoflush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214271/c-equivalent-of-autoflush-flush-stdout-after-each-write)

Comment: cmd not use stdio at all

Comment: true, but the MSDN code in the link he shared (the one he is running from the cmd) does.

Comment: no. even code example under link not use stdio but call `WriteFile` and `ReadFile`. cmd also not use stdio

Comment: What do you think the header `#include <stdio.h>` and all the `printf()` in the code does, then?

Comment: in example used `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` than and question was not about this example but about cmd.exe. your answer is wrong. cmd exe not use stdio and no any autoflush

Comment: Just to be clear for the purposes of this question, please note that cmd.exe bypasses C standard (e.g. `fwrite`) and low (e.g. `_write`) I/O to instead use the Windows API directly.

Comment: The question is, why when using cmd.exe to run the code in the MSDN code example then `except that for stdout if the process doesn't flush then I don't see the output of the process immediately`.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel, Jorge wants to know what cmd.exe is doing to send data directly to the pipe without a `flush`, and the answer is simply that cmd.exe does not use standard I/O at all in this case -- no `fwrite`, no `printf`. It writes directly to the pipe via `WriteFile`.

Comment: The question is: When debugging an app in Visual Studio it doesn't require a ``fflush(stdout)`` every time I printf, but in a debugged child process I create it does. What I can do to eliminate the buffering in the child process that I'm debugging? I don't control whether the child process uses std or winapi. This answer would be appropriate if I can invoke setvbuf in a child process, but I can't figure out how to do so. If I can remove buffering from a child process, that's the answer.

Comment: @JorgeRodriguez, in Linux there's a `stdbuf` program for this, but it relies on a couple features that are not generically supported in Windows: (1) the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable that allows injecting shared libraries into a process before the normally loaded libraries and (2) that there's typically only one well-known C runtime (libc.so.6) loaded in the global namespace, thus making it reliable to call `setvbuf` before the application's `main` entry point is called. Windows has no such loader hook, no global namespace for loaded modules, and commonly has multiple CRTs in a process.

Comment: @JorgeRodriguez, there's also the Expect pty approach. If there's not much output, you can create a console screen buffer for the child, with the maximum 9,999 lines. Then read it at the end via `ReadConsoleOutputW`. Or actively poll/scrape its contents, but that's not very reliable. Windows 10 adds pseudoconsole support. This allows you to start a child process attached to a custom console (conhost.exe), so the child has console I/O instead of pipes. On the backend, this console and your process communicate via UTF-8 virtual-terminal streams over a pair of pipes (input & output).

Comment: The Windows debug app does insert a fake breakpoint before it invokes main which allows me to do arbitrary operations on the guest process, so if I can figure out what to call then I know where to put it, but there’s no setvbuf for external processes equivalent. My stopgap is that I can write some code to the guest process that calls this, set RIP to that code, and then return it when done... super hacky. I’m hoping for some native support.

Answer (score 0):

cmd.exe use direct winapi calls `WriteFile` or `WriteConsoleW` for print to stdout. so if you want to do so too - you can also use this winapi.

when stdout is file:

[image]

when stdout is console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can't find out how the Visual Studio implement this logic.

To solve your issue, prevent the parent process blocking and print the output from the child process, you can check the read size returned from `ReadFile` in your parent process to decide to read continue or stop if you can't control the child process.

```
for (;;)
{
    bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

    bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf,
        dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess) break;

    // Check if there is more data to read, if not break.
    if (dwRead < BUFSIZE)
        break;
}
```