# Implement C# Process.OutputDataReceived in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

C# has this nice `Process.OutputDataReceived()` method that occurs when each time the process write a line to `stdout`, and for some reason I need this implementation in C++, for **Windows only**. I tried `boost::process` with async io, something like

```cpp
    boost::asio::async_read(ap, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
        [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size)
        {
            std::cout << buf.data() << '\n';
        });
```

However the callback only happens once, and won't continue if the buffer is not big enough. I want the functionality that it keeps on "monitoring" the child process until it exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.BeginOutputReadLine()` simply starts an async task that monitors the process's stdout and fires `OutputDataReceived()` whenever any data is received.

In C++, that basically boils down to calling `CreateProcess()`, redirecting its STDOUT to a local pipe, and then you can use `PeekNamedPipe()` or overlapped I/O to monitor and read the pipe asynchronously, or you can just read from the pipe synchronously in a separate worker thread.

Comment: Can only make it work with anonymous pipe (thus losing async ability) but having no luck with named pipe. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: [Overlapped I/O on anonymous pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645/overlapped-i-o-on-anonymous-pipe)